# How to create a pandas DataFrame from its indexes and a two variable function?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

This is a common pattern I've been using:

```
rows = ['Joe','Amy','Tom']
columns = ['account_no', 'balance']

def f(row, column):
    '''Fetches value from database'''
    return np.random.random()

pd.DataFrame([[f(row, column) for column in columns] for  row in rows], index=rows, columns=columns)
```

If the rows and columns are numerical, I can also use np.meshgrid:

```
rows = [1,2,3]
columns = [4,5]

pd.DataFrame(np.vectorize(f)(xs, ys), index=rows, columns=columns)
```

My question is, what is the most elegant/Pythonic/"pandasic"/fastest/most readable way to doing this in the general case?

Thanks!

Comment: @EdChum: This is not a question about putting random values in a DataFrame. In reality my function `f` fetches a value from a database and that value will depend on both inputs `row` and `column`, unlike the version presented here.

Comment: @EdChum: yes, that is true, but it's not relevant to my question. At no point do I suggest doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a way of doing this could be to turn your function into a ufunc, and then use [outer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html)

```
import numpy as np
uf = np.frompyfunc(f, 2, 1) # f has 2 inputs, 1 outputs
pd.DataFrame(uf.outer(rows, columns), index=rows, columns=columns)
```

one criterion you have above though is 'most readable' for which I'd say your existing for loop solution is best.

Comment: Thank you kind stranger!